# What is the meaning of @ symbol in SQL*Plus script?

Tags: oracle

I am going through SQL*Plus script and came across set of lines that has below lines:

```
@test_data/EMPLOYEE.dat
@test_data/ADDRESS.dat
```

The `.dat` has some SQL code inside them. I tried to search in internet what the `@` symbole indicates but I did not get any results. I am new to SQL*Plus, please let me know what this symbol indicates.

Comment: This is not PL/SQL. It's [SQL*Plus syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve002.htm), which can also be used in SQL Developer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is about sql*plus scripting, we use this symbol to call scripts from external files.

Answer (score 1):

@ is used to call scripts from the external files

From the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve002.htm):

> Runs the SQL*Plus statements in the specified script. The script can
>   be called from the local file system or from a web server. The @
>   command functions similarly to @@ and START.

Answer (score 0):

It is used to run the scripts from another file. eg:

```
SQL> @PreImport.sql
```